# Calling a specific dataframe column for function in a nested for loop using vectors in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've searched a lot and couldn't find an answer. I am working in R. I have a dataframe with two types of columns - numeric columns and charcater columns. I am trying to calculate descriptive statistics for the numeric variable columns, according to grouping variables from the character columns (I do this with the describeBy function from the psych library, works fine outsdie of the loops). In addition, I would like to run the same analysis on a subset of the rows from the original dataframe, so I created another subsetted dataframe.
So, I have two dataframes, each with three character columns and four numeric columns. The dataframes looks like this:

```
    MET.1   CEM.2   CEM.3   par aic od  wd
1   healthy healthy healthy 1   6   279 126
2   healthy healthy cem     1   6   244 159
3   met     healthy healthy 1   8   222 131
4   met     cem     healthy 1   4   219 122
5   healthy healthy healthy 1   3   216 129
6   healthy healthy healthy 3   6   204 107
```

to reproduce:

```
df <- data.frame(MET.1 = c("healthy", "healthy", "met", "met", 
"healthy", "healthy"), CEM.2 = c("healthy", "healthy", "healthy", 
"cem", "healthy", "healthy"), CEM.3 = c("healthy", "cem", 
"healthy", "healthy", "healthy", "healthy"), par = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), aic = c(6L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 6L), od = c(279L, 
244L, 222L, 219L, 216L, 204L), wd = c(126L, 159L, 131L, 122L, 
129L, 107L))
```

I want to run the describeBy function for each numeric column (4 times) by each grouping column (3 times) in each dataframe (2 times) - 24 times in three nested loops, and finally join them to one dataframe. I thought of taking each of these parameters and turn them into a character vector, and then call the apropriate columns to the describeBy function using variables from these vectors. I tried something like this:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("psych")
#create vectors containing numerical columns, charcter columns and different dataframe names
numcol = c("par", "aic", "od", "wd")
charcol = c("MET.1", "CEM.2", "CEM.3")
dataset = c("df","df.subset")
# create vector of output objects for easy use of rbind later...
chunks = c()

#for each dataframe, charcter column and numeric column
for (i in 1:length(dataset)) {
  for (j in 1:length(charcol)) {
    for (k in 1:length(numcol)) {
        #create numeric column name in specific dataframe
        param = paste0(dataset[i],"$",numcol[k])
        #create character column name in specific dataframe
        group = paste0(dataset[i],"$",charcol[j])
        # try to apply function by using above created column names - DOESN'T WORK
        paste0(numcol[k],charcol[j],dataset[i]) = do.call(rbind, describeBy(param, group = group))
        #add resulting dataframe name to vector for use in rbind at the end of the loop
        chunks = c(chunks,paste0(numcol[k],charcol[j],dataset[i]))
      }
    }
}
out.df = rbind(chunks)
```

Doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
```

I checked each step in the loops manually and the problem is with calling the specific column name from a specific dataframe to the function using the variables I created. what I tried to do is to represent the column name i.e. DataFrame$Column. Also tried a few versions with square brackets, e.g. `dataset[i][,numcol[k]]` to no avail. If anyone knows how to solve this or has a workaround please let me know.
Cheers,
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the output of `describeBy` function in a list and you are right the issue is with how you access the column names. You cannot use `$` to access column names when they are character values use double brackets (`[[]]`).

```
library(psych)

numcol = c("par", "aic", "od", "wd")
charcol = c("MET.1", "CEM.2", "CEM.3")
dataset = list(df, df.subset)
output_list <- vector('list', length(numcol) * length(charcol) * length(dataset))
x <- 0

for (i in seq_along(dataset)) {
  for (j in charcol) {
    for (k in numcol) {
      x <- x + 1
      output_list[[x]] <- describeBy(dataset[[i]][[k]],group = dataset[[i]][[j]])
    }
  }
}
```

`output_list` would have a list of `describeBy` outputs in one list.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, works great. Quick follow up question - how do I turn this list of lists of data.frame(s) into one data frame? ```rbind``` just turns it into another list...

Comment: @RonSicsic It returns a `describeBy` object, you need to convert each one of it into a dataframe. So you can try either `result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(output_list, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, data.frame))))` Or using `purrr` : `result <- map_df(output_list, ~map_df(.x, data.frame))`

Comment: Cheers Ronak, You've been very helpful. The first option worked better for me as it retains the list names, this way I know which row came from which object.

Comment: What is a "df.subset" in a "dataset = list"?